# How to handle a conflicting suggested tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I just ran into a suggested tag wiki for [was](/questions/tagged/was). 
https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/85144

The proposed text says that it means

> Windows Process Activation Service (WAS)

I always though it meant

> IBM WebSphere Application Server (WAS)

How do I handle this? Approve or Reject?

Comment: Uh, looking at the existing questions with that tag, it looks like your assumption is the most *popular*, but certainly not the only one. This tag appears to be a candidate for splitting up into two separate, more clearly labeled alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If almost all questions tagged [was](/questions/tagged/was) are about the Windows WAS: accept the suggestion, retag the few questions that aren't about the Windows WAS.

If almost all questions tagged [was](/questions/tagged/was) are about the IBM WAS: reject the suggestion, retag the few questions that aren't about the IBM WAS.

If [was](/questions/tagged/was) is an ambiguous tag, with a significant number of questions about either topic, then the tag should be split, perhaps into [windows-was](/questions/tagged/windows-was) or [ibm-was](/questions/tagged/ibm-was). (I have no idea if these particular names are appropriate.) Raise the issue on [metaso]; try to get the attention of the top people in the tag. Hopefully a consensus on tag names will be reached, then get people to help retag the questions until the ambiguous tag is no more. Optionally, once the new tag names have been agreed on, request that the developers blacklist the ambiguous tag.

Comment: The proposal is accepted by now, so I didn't  have to decide. Looking at the questions, they are unfortunately **very** evenly distributed between MS and IBM.